# Chrome DevTools: What is the difference between the Network.loadingFinished and Network.dataReceived events?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I would please like to know:

1. What is the purpose of the [Network.loadingFinished](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-loadingFinished) event? What exactly does the documentation mean when it says, "Fired when HTTP request has finished loading?"
2. How is this event different than the request's *last* [Network.dataReceived](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-dataReceived) event?

At first, my impression was that the Network.loadingFinished event signaled the end of the load time of a particular request, where "load time" is defined as the time at which the last payload packet was received. However, if this is true, then the timestamp of Network.loadingFinished and the timestamp of the last Network.dataReceived would be equal; yet, this is not the case.

Here is an example where the last Network.dataReceived event's timestamp is larger than Network.loadingFinished event's timestamp:

[image]

And here is an example of the opposite situation:

[image]